# jQuery - disable function temporarily then enable it again

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to disable function from running and enable it after certain timeout.

For example, I want to stop the first script from looping after a while and then start it again.

JS

```
// Script that loops

function messages() {

  setInterval(function() {

    setTimeout(function() {
      alert("Hello!");
    }, 2000);  

    setTimeout(function() {
      alert("I said hello!");
    }, 10000);  

  }, 20000);  // It's looping every 20 sec

}

// Script with timeout to stop the loop

setTimeout(function() {
  messages.stop();
}, 60000);  // Stop it after 60 sec

setTimeout(function() {
  messages.start();
}, 120000);  // Start again it after 120 sec
```

Can this be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope it will help you.

```js
function messages() {

      var main = setInterval(function() {


        setTimeout(function() {
          alert("Hello!");
        }, 2000); 

     
  

        setTimeout(function() {
          alert("I said hello!");
        }, 10000);  


      }, 20000);  // It's looping every 20 sec
        
     
    setTimeout(function() {
        clearInterval(main);
    }, 60000);  // stop again it after 60 sec
        
 
    setTimeout(function() {
         messages();
    }, 120000); // start again it after 120 sec
        
    }
    
    messages();
```

**UPDATED**

Comment: This actually will do! Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

If it's inside a loop can't you:

```
// the start method turns a variable to true for example in the inner function scope
if (start) {
  setTimeout((data) => data, 25000);
}
```

Would this work? Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks, but if it gets more complicated, I would rather not recalculate how much time I need. Wish there was a way to enable and disable as it's needed in the given time.